# How do I reset my character position on contact?

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I have a character in my 2d platformer, and I also have an enemy block that moves between two points.

On contact, I want to reset the position of the character to its original position, as it has died.

With my current code, the player's position is only set to the original position while in contact with the enemy fixture, and does not stay there after as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I cannot figure out what needs to be done to resolve this.

character.cpp

```
/*!
\file character.cpp
*/

#include "character.h"

Character::Character(b2World * world, const sf::Vector2f& position, const sf::Vector2f &size, const float orientation, sf::Texture *texture)
{
    b2BodyDef l_bodyDef;
    b2PolygonShape l_shape;
    b2FixtureDef l_fixtureDef;

    l_bodyDef.position.Set(position.x, position.y);
    l_bodyDef.angle = orientation * DEG2RAD;
    l_bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    m_body = world->CreateBody(&l_bodyDef);
    m_body->SetFixedRotation(true);
    m_body->SetUserData(this); // used by our contact listener

    l_shape.SetAsBox(size.x * 0.5f, size.y * 0.5f);
    l_shape.m_radius = 0.0f;

    l_fixtureDef.density = mk_fDensity;
    l_fixtureDef.friction = mk_fFriction;
    l_fixtureDef.restitution = 0.f;
    l_fixtureDef.shape = &l_shape;

    m_body->CreateFixture(&l_fixtureDef);

    l_shape.SetAsBox(size.x * 0.4, size.y * 0.001f, b2Vec2(0.f, size.y * 0.5f), 0.f);
    b2Fixture* bodyFixture = m_body->CreateFixture(&l_fixtureDef);
    bodyFixture->SetUserData((void *)PhysicalThing::CHARACTER);

    l_shape.SetAsBox(size.x * 0.4f, size.y * 0.001f, b2Vec2(0.f, size.y * 0.5f), 0.f);
    l_fixtureDef.isSensor = true; //Make it a sensor
    b2Fixture* footSensorFixture = m_body->CreateFixture(&l_fixtureDef);
    footSensorFixture->SetUserData((void *)PhysicalThing::CHARACTER);

    setPosition(position);
    setSize(size);
    setOrigin(size * 0.5f);
    setTexture(texture);
    setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 28, 68));
    setRotation(orientation);
    setOutlineThickness(0.f);

    originPosition = position;
}

void Character::update()
{
    b2Vec2 pos = m_body->GetPosition();
    setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
    float angle = m_body->GetAngle()* RAD2DEG;
    setRotation(angle);

    b2Vec2 vel = m_body->GetLinearVelocity();
    float velChange = mySpeed - vel.x;
    float impulse = m_body->GetMass() * velChange;
    m_body->ApplyLinearImpulseToCenter(b2Vec2(impulse, 0.f), true);

    if (m_movingStates[LEFT])
    {
        mySpeed = -2.0f;
        direction = -1;
        setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(81, 0, 54, 66));
        setScale(direction * 2, 1);
    }

    if (m_movingStates[RIGHT])
    {
        mySpeed = 2.0f;
        direction = 1;
        setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(81, 0, 54, 66));
        setScale(direction * 2, 1);
    }

    if (m_sit)
    {
        if((int)sitType->GetUserData() == PhysicalThing::KINEMATICBLOCK)
        {
            m_body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(m_body->GetLinearVelocity().x + sitType->GetBody()->GetLinearVelocity().x, m_body->GetLinearVelocity().y + sitType->GetBody()->GetLinearVelocity().y));
        }
    }

    if (damage)
    {
        setPosition(originPosition);
    }

    if (m_movingStates[JUMP] && m_sit)
    {
        m_body->ApplyLinearImpulseToCenter(b2Vec2(0.f, -0.35f), true);
        setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(81, 0, 54, 66));
        setScale(direction * 2, 1);
    }

    if (!m_movingStates[LEFT] && !m_movingStates[RIGHT])
    {
        mySpeed = 0.f;
        setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 28, 68));
        setScale(direction, 1);
    }
}

void Character::onKeyPress(sf::Event event)
{
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)m_movingStates[LEFT] = true;
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)m_movingStates[RIGHT] = true;
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)m_movingStates[JUMP] = true;
}

void Character::onKeyRelease(sf::Event event)
{
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left) m_movingStates[LEFT] = false;
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right) m_movingStates[RIGHT] = false;
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space) m_movingStates[JUMP] = false;
}

void Character::sitOn(b2Fixture * other)
{
    m_sit = true;
    sitType = other;
}

void Character::sitOff(b2Fixture * other)
{
    m_sit = false;
    sitType = nullptr;
}

void Character::onDamage(b2Fixture * other)
{
    damage = true;
    lives--;
}

void Character::offDamage(b2Fixture * other)
{
    damage = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read, look in this block:

```
if (damage)
{
    setPosition(originPosition);
}
```

You move the character but you don't set it's new position accordingly. That's why it goes back to it's old position after the collision.

What you mean to do is something along these lines (I'm leaving the details up to you, you know what you're doing):

```
if (damage)
{
    pos.x = originPosition.x;
    pos.y = originPosition.y;
}
```

Hope it helps. Have fun!

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I have tried setting pos.x and y to the newly set position, but I'm, still having the same error

Comment: Ok, what are `position`, `pos` and `originalPosition` used for?

Comment: Position is the initial position set when creating the object, pos is a variable used to constantly update the player position when moved, and original position is a variable set to reference the position variable in other functions.

Comment: Seems like something is assigning value to `pos` out of turn, but I can't spot it in this code.

Comment: The only other place I can see that assigns the pos to anything is at the beginning of the update function for this class, its the only other place it's used.

Comment: Do you have a git repo or something? This would need debugging more than a glance.

Comment: Managed to resolve it, decided to delete the character block and reset its position and state etc. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: @JordanLewis Good job!